# mercurial: automatically pulling an external library under development

Tags: mercurial

I work on `project1` which uses `module1` developed independently. They both reside on the same mercurial server (development for `project1` and `module1` is done locally, then commits are pushed to a server.  Both are separate, independent repositories).

How can I ensure that, when pulling for changes in `project1`, I also pull `module1` (with a warning if my local `module1` requires a merge (in the case I would have had worked on `module1` in the meantime))?

Comment: When you say project1 and module1 are on the same 'mercurial server', do you mean they are 2 projects within the same repo, or 2 seperate HG repos being hosted on the same box ?

Comment: They are two separate repos being hosted on the same server, I will update the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at attaching module1 as a subrepo to project1, but this won't work exactly the way you want it to. This allows you to develop module1 as its own repo, but when developing project1, each changeset will be stamped with the changeset of module1 in the subrepo at the time of commit.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/

So this won't guarantee that you have the latest version of module1 whenever you pull project1, but it will guarantee that you at least have module1 up to the version that was used with a particular version of project1.

Alternatively, since by default mercurial doesn't support what you are asking exactly,you can write your own hook for the pull command (a hook is a script that gets triggered when you do the action it is hooked to), which reads the .hgsub command and does a recursive pull and update of all subrepos.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook

You can probably accomplish this without subrepos, but in that case I'd advise you to have some file commited to project1 that your hook can read, which tells it what repos to pull. You should be able to use the normal output from pulls, or possibly run hg advice, to give feedback about needing to merge.

Comment: Thanks. I did thing about subrepositories but since module1 will be in reality used by several projects I cannot tie it to only one of them. I also thought about a hook (I use some elsewhere) but was hoping for a generic Mercurial mechanism to handle such cases. I will therefore think about how to best use the hook mechanism to fit to my case.

Comment: @WoJ. You can still use module1 in other projects even if its a SubRepo or project1. What using a subrepo does is basically say, "at this revision of repo project1 I will automatically pull this revision of repo module1". module1 can still exist as its own repo, tied as a subrepo to other repos. Subrepos still don't accomplish quite what you specified though.

Comment: what I meant is that I have several projects (1, 2, 3, ...) which rely in the same way on module1. As far as I know a subrepository is a subrepository of exactly one other (in other words, two separate repositories cannot have one common subrepository)

Comment: @WoJ. Sorry, I did not express myself clearly, but that is what I thought you meant, and you can infact have multiple repos using module1 as a subrepo. You can look at http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#remote-subrepositories for an idea of how this is done.